# express with typescript failed to lookup views directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, tsconfig

I want to use typescript to develop a express server. set './bin' as outDir. then the compiled js file throw an error: "failed to lookup views directory"..

```
Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "D:\work\nodejs\ly-node-test-site\bin\views"
at EventEmitter.render (D:\work\nodejs\ly-node-test-site\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
at ServerResponse.render (D:\work\nodejs\ly-node-test-site\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
at D:\work\nodejs\ly-node-test-site\bin\src\app.js:56:9
```

I see the output file referenced a wrong path. but don't know how to config it.
My project path is

[image]

Comment: I found a way to let it worked. change the view engine setup config path.   "app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../../views'));" ......